# Confusion about DO loop in a FORTRAN program (Beginner level)

Tags: fortran

I'm just starting out learning to program and FORTRAN 95 is my first language. I'm trying to complete Question 4 i) at the bottom of page 45 of [this](http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/david/fplecs12.pdf) pdf file. For reference, here is my whole source code:

```
PROGRAM PARACHUTIST
! Tabulation of parachutist's descent z and and speed zdot
! as functions of time t

 !Assign the program's associated constants

IMPLICIT NONE
  REAL z, zdot, g, U1, U2, z0, u0, t0, q0, t, x,c,s
INTEGER I


g=9.8
U1=54
U2=5
!Break z0 down a little with q0
q0=COSH(g*t0/U1)
z0=U1**2/g*LOG(q0)
u0=U1*TANH(g*t0/U1)

  !Prompt for and read in the free-fall time

  Print*, 'Input free-fall time in seconds:'
  Read*, t0

  !Print the table headings
  WRITE(*,1000)

1000 FORMAT (6X, 'TIME', 6X, 'DISTANCE', 6X, 'VELOCITY', /6X, '(SEC)', 7X, '(M)', 10X, '(M/SEC)',&
    /6X, '0.0', 10X, '0.0', 10X, '0.0' )

  !Loop covering the specified times
  t=0
! I know I'm meant to start some DO loop here, but unsure
! how to set it up. 
     ! Calculate the distance above ground
200         IF(t<=15) THEN
        x=g*t/U1
        z=U1**2/g*LOG(COSH(x))
        zdot=U1*TANH(x)
     Elseif(t>15) THEN
        x=g*(t-t0)/U2  !store re-used expressions
        c=cosh(x)
        s=sinh(x)
        z= z0 + (U2**2/g)*LOG(c+ u0/U2*s)
        zdot=U2*(U2*s+u0*c)/(U2*c+u0*s) 
     Endif

     !Print a line of table using T formats
     WRITE(*,100) t, z, zdot
100      Format(4X, F5.2, 6X, F7.2, 6X, F7.2)

     !Stop with message if landed
     If(z.GE.500) THEN
    STOP

     !If we haven't yet landed then increment t as in 
    !   problem specs
     If(t<15) then
        t=t+1

     Elseif(t.GE.15) then
        t=t+10
ENDIF
GOTO 200
300 STOP
ENDIF
  !End of the t-loop

END PROGRAM PARACHUTIST
```

Now, I think I've assigned variable types/values correctly and printed out the headings in a suitable format (though I'm never certain, if you see any errors please tell me), my main problem occurs from "!Loop covering the specified times". That whole block of code, to be honest, I'm totally confused about. I'm not really certain about how to construct the loop, I've only done them on much simpler problems and can't wrap my head around this one. Can someone please take a look and give me some suggestions?

Comment: I think this question is best suited for SO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debugging DO loop / IF blocks in a Fortran 90 program (Beginner level)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371441/debugging-do-loop-if-blocks-in-a-fortran-90-program-beginner-level)

Answer (score 2):

If I've read it correctly, your program models the descent of a parachutist  For the first 15 seconds the parachutist descends at one rate, and you update position and velocity every second, after 15 seconds a different rate of descent applies and you update position and velocity every 10 seconds.  The simulation continues until the position reaches 500, I guess that is the distance to the ground when the parachutist jumps.  If I've misunderstood some of what follows will be moderately erroneous

One approach, not the only and maybe not the best, would be to structure your program like this:

```
    ... initialise stuff ...
    t = 0
    DO
        IF (t<=15) THEN
            ...do stuff...
            t = t+1
        ELSE ! no need for a else if (t>15) here
            ...do other stuff...
            t = t+10
        END IF
        ... write stuff ...
        IF (Z>=500.0) EXIT

    END DO
```

Note that I've used the EXIT statement on the test to terminate the loop, STOP stops the program, EXIT breaks out of the nearest enclosing loop and gives you the opportunity (which may not strictly be necessary in this program but will be in more complex ones that you will eventually write) to tidy up before the program stops.

Since you confess to being new to Fortran, here's some further unsolicited advice;

- Collect your Format statements in one location within your program.  I particularly don't like the location of your statement 100 inside the loop.
- If you find yourself writing GOTO to implement a loop you've done something wrong.
- Numeric statement labels are almost entirely unnecessary in Fortran after 90; some of what you have written looks a lot like FORTAN77.
- You've mixed old-style relational operators (e.g. .GE.) with new-style (e.g. >=).  Stick to one style, better the new but if you can't do that for some odd reason stick to the old style.

Answer (score 0):

"I'm ment to start some sort of do loop here..."

You probably want a WHILE loop. In English it would be

"while z is less than 500 {...}"

The STOP would then be after the loop.

There are lots of "best practices" that you will learn as you go along.
One of them is to give all of the constants a name. 
This is called "no magic numbers".

Comment: OP has named all variables, no sign of any magic numbers in the code posted.  Some of the variable names are a little short and cryptic perhaps.